# nginx-ingress not forwarding to dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, kubernetes-dashboard

Hello and thank you for taking the time to read my question.

First, I have an EKS cluster setup to use public and private subnets.

I generated the cluster using cloudformation as described at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started-console.html#vpc-create

I then initialized helm by creating a service account for tiller via `kubectl apply -f (below file)`:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: tiller
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: tiller
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: tiller
    namespace: kube-system
```

and then `helm init --service-account=tiller`
followed by `helm repo update`

I then used helm to install the nginx-ingress controller via:

```
helm install --name nginx-ingress \
        --namespace nginx-project \
        stable/nginx-ingress \
        -f nginx-ingress-values.yaml
```

where my nginx-ingress-values.yaml is:

```
controller:
  service:
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-access-log-emit-interval: "60"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-access-log-enabled: "true"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-access-log-s3-bucket-name: "abc-us-west-2-elb-access-logs"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-access-log-s3-bucket-prefix: "vault-cluster/nginx"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: "arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:123456789:certificate/bb35b4c4-..."
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "http"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "https"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: "60"
```

And so far everything looks great, I see the ELB get created and hooked up to use acm for https

I then install kubernetes-dashboard via:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v1.10.1/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

and I can access it via `kubectl proxy`

But when I add an ingress rule for dashboard via:
`kubectl apply -f dashboard-ingress.yaml`
Where dashboard-ingress.yaml is:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dashboard
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
#  tls:
#  - hosts:
#    - abc.def.com
  rules:
  - host: abc.def.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /dashboard
        backend:
          serviceName: kubernetes-dashboard
          servicePort: 8443
```

then when I try to go http://abc.def.com/ I get stuck in an infinite redirect loop.

same for https://abc.def.com/
and
http://abc.def.com/dashboard

I am new to kubernetes and very stuck on this one. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated

**UPDATE - 9/5/2019:**
When I take out the tls block from the ingress.yaml I then get

to the nginx backend but http://abc.def.com forwards me to https://abc.def.com and I get a 502 Bad Gateway from openresty/1.15.8.1

when I then try to go to https://abc.def.com/dashboard

I get "404 page not found" which is a response from the nginx-ingress controller as I understand it.

**UPDATE - 9/6/2019:**
Thanks so much to mk_sta for the answer below which helped me understand what I was missing.

For anyone reading this in the future, my nginx-ingress install via helm works as expected but my kubernetes-dashboard install was missing some key annotations. In the end I was able to configure helm to install the kubernetes-dashboard via:

```
helm install --name kubernetes-dashboard \
    --namespace kube-system \
    stable/kubernetes-dashboard \
    -f kubernetes-dashboard-values.yaml
```

where kubernetes-dashboard-values.yaml is:

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  hosts: [abc.def.com]
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  paths: [/dashboard(/|$)(.*)]
```

I can then access dashboard at http://abc.def.com/dashboard/ and https://abc.def.com/dashboard/

For some reason if I leave off the trailing slash it does not work however.

This is good enough for me at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you've used wrong location path `/dashboard` within yours origin `Ingress` configuration, even more the relevant *[K8s dashboard](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard) UI* endpoint is exposed on `443` port by default across the corresponded K8s [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) resource, whenever you've not customized this setting.

```
ports:
- port: 443
  protocol: TCP
  targetPort: 8443
```

In order to get a proper path based [routing](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/basic-usage/), override existing parameters with the following arguments:

```
paths:
- path: /
  backend:
    serviceName: kubernetes-dashboard
    servicePort: 443
```

Once you've decided accessing *K8s dashboard UI* through indirect path holder URL (*https://abc.def.com/dashboard*), you can manage applying [Rewrite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) rules in order to transparently change a part of the authentic URL and transmit requests to the faithful target path. Actually, *[Nginx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) Ingress controller* adds this functionality via specific `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` [annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#rewrite):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dashboard
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
#  tls:
#  - hosts:
#    - abc.def.com
  rules:
  - host: abc.def.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /dashboard(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: kubernetes-dashboard
          servicePort: 443
```

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if your cluster doesn't have `nginx` as the default ingress class, and your ingress manifest doesn't specify one.

You can try one of the following:
- Upgrade your NGINX-ingress installation with `controller.ingressClass` set to `nginx` (with this, all ingresses created will use NGINX-ingress by default)
- Add the `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx` annotation to your ingress yaml to specify that you want NGINX-ingress to handle it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I checked and this is the default setting in the helm chart: 
https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/nginx-ingress/values.yaml#L60